# Angular 2 Quickstart - my-app component not loading

Tags: angular, typescript

Trying to learn angular so I've started with the quickstart tutorial for TypeScript in their website (https://angular.io/guide/quickstart)

I'm working on ubuntu 14.04.

I've followed through each step, and at the end I'm not getting any errors, but the component does not load. Instead, the only thing I am seeing is "Loading..." instead of the main component "my-app".

[what i see in my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fl6Px.png)

the **index.html**:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app/app.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

I see no point in showing the rest of the configuration files because they are exactly like the ones in the tutorial. The only change is that I've changed **tsconfig.json** to

`"target": "es6",`

because it didn't work otherwise.

What can be the problem? Why is it not loading my main component?

**Edit:** these are the errors in my browser console:

```
 2 http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

 systemjs.config.js:46 Uncaught TypeError: System.config is not a function

 http://localhost:3000/app/ Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

 app:18 Not Found: http://localhost:3000/app
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/app(anonymous function) @ app:18

 http://localhost:3000/app/ Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: I think you need to bootstrap the application

Comment: Open your console and check the err message

Comment: Which IDE do you use?

Answer (score 1):

I had kind of similar problem and was finally able to find where the problem is.

In my case, when I ran `npm start` in browser console error was `XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js`.I realized that I am missing `main.js`, but I have `/app/main.ts`.

Typescript files(.ts) were not compiled to JS(.js) files. Then it was found that an additional character "\" at the end of tsconfig.json file. It was not visible in explorer or in Atom, untill in Terminal typed `tsconfig` and pressed Tab key for auto completion. It shown that there is an additional character at the end of the file name. Then with this command `$ mv tsconfig.json\  tsconfig.json`, the name was changed. And then with npm start, it just worked fine.

So please check all your file names in console. Hope your one will also work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add main.ts (Refer step 3 from tutorial - https://angular.io/guide/quickstart)

Comment: no... i have added it.

ziv@ziv-K55A:~/angular2-quickstart/app$ cat main.ts
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
bootstrap(AppComponent);

Comment: What about systemjs.config.js? If all files are there then check your browser console for errors

Comment: I edited the original post and added the console errors. the files are there, but there seems to be a problem with systemjs.config.js....

Comment: After running npm install command, do you see 'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js' ?

Comment: Yes: ziv@ziv-K55A:~/angular2-quickstart/node_modules/systemjs/dist$ ls
system-csp-production.js      system-polyfills.js.map
system-csp-production.js.map  system-polyfills.src.js
system-csp-production.src.js  system-register-only.js
system.js                     system-register-only.js.map
system.js.map                 system-register-only.src.js
system-polyfills.js           system.src.js

Comment: First, Make sure you have latest version of npm. Then, can you try these steps- 1. Delete node_modules folder. 2. change back to "target": "es5" in tsconfig.json 3. run npm install.

Comment: If this still didn't worked then upload your code to github or plnker or jsfiddle

Comment: Any luck with your issue?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing

```
<base href="/">
```

in your index.html file

index.html should look like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Frontend</title>
<base href="/">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```